# Socket IO can't emit

Tags: node.js, sockets

For a few days I've been trying to get the socket.io chat example to work from [here](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/). First I tried it by typing everything myself. But it didnt work. After that I tried it with the files from [github](https://github.com/rauchg/chat-example).

the part

After I got the files from github I tried it did not work I have run

```
npm install
```

and it downloaded the dependencies into the node_modules folder, I also ran

```
 npm install --save express@4.10.2
 npm install --save socket.io
```

I got no errors on any of the commands.

I start the program with

```
node index.js
```

Which gives me the following message:

listening on *:30000

If I go to localhost:3000, I get the chat application as in the example. But no messages show up when posting the form.

However, when I use the following code to check connection:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){ 
        console.log('user connected');
   });
```

it works, so the problem is in emitting data.

Also, the following code works:

server index.js

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  var tweet = {user: "nodesource", text: "Hello, world!"};

    // to make things interesting, have it send every second
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        socket.emit("tweet", tweet);
        console.log("tweeting");
    }, 1000);

    socket.on("disconnect", function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
});
```

Client

```
socket.on("tweet", function(tweet) {
    // todo: add the tweet as a DOM node

    console.log("tweet from", tweet.username);
    console.log("contents:", tweet.text);
});
```

**So emitting and receiving from the server to the client works.**

**What I've tried**

- Run in different browsers
- Run on different PC's
- Copy from github
- Type everything myself
- Check the console in Chrome for errors (no errors found)
- Change ports
- Different paths (used c:\chat , d:\chat, c:\personalfiles\chat )
- Disable firewall

**What works**

- When following the tutorial, the part where a user connects and gets logged on the console work.
- I get the chat page
- Console says its listening
- No errors

Any tips on how to solve this, or how to find what's wrong?

**My index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
          console.log('Send message');
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**My index.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: So, I assume, console does not say, that user is connected?

Comment: Nope it does nothing, only says its listening. @yergo

Comment: I that case I kindly request for your `index.js` file along with `index.html` file mentioned in [manual](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/). I smell for something missed there.

Comment: @yergo added them, i tried to put the script tags in the head but did not make any difference. at the moment its an exact copy of the github files mentioned in the beginning.

Comment: Hate that. Copied, npm installed, fired up and... Works. Not telling that user is connected (because in that example its not implemented) but messages sends from tab to tab and I do can chat...

Comment: could you give me the exact steps, first you donwloaded the files, then run npm install, then run node index.js thats all or any more steps ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73083/discussion-between-yergo-and-sven-b).

Comment: Why do you add **socket.io** two times in `index.html`?

Comment: @zaynetro Just to make sure it was loading correctly i tried both seperatly, made no difference.

Comment: @SvenB, tested on mac using chrome 41 with no firewall, worked straight out of a box. No errors in browser console?

Comment: @zaynetro nope no errors, not on the browser console, and not in the node console

Comment: I would try to adding some events on client side like `socket.on('connect', function () { console.log('connected'); });` There are plenty of them [See Events](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/)

Comment: @zaynetro its connected else the : io.on('connection', function(socket){ 
        console.log('user connected');
   }); wouldnt work (tried and logged connected), also added  socket.on('error', function(err){
          console.log("Error: "+err.message);
      }) but didnt get any errors

Comment: You didn't manage to run this example on each PC you tried?

Comment: @zaynetro i tried it on 2 pc's both didnt work. i didnt copy the files but followed the tutorial again, Again i get the a user connected/disconected message but when trying to emit nothing happens. also i tried to copy it from github and run the commands on the other pc still didnt work.

Comment: By the way try changing event name from `chat message` to something with one word like `message`.

Comment: @zaynetro tried it no difference, i started all over following, https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-socketio and that works. but i cant get the offical tutorial to work..

Comment: @SvenB I tried this chat example on Windows 10 and it worked. Shouldn't be a problem with socket.io set up.

Comment: @SvenB tried again with ur code nd it seems to work. Have u tried with '<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js">' in index.html

Answer (score 1):

try this (for version <= 0.8):

```
io.configure(function () { 
   io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
   io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});
```

for version 1.0.x it would be something like:

```
var io  = require('socket.io').listen(http, {
    "transports": ['websocket', 
                   'flashsocket', 
                   'htmlfile', 
                   'xhr-polling', 
                   'jsonp-polling', 
                   'polling'],
    "polling duration": 10
});
```

Comment: i have old version, updated. At least try it, or different polling methods -- seems like it's only windows problem, i can't reproduce it on *nix

Answer (score 1):

Yours:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

Are you sure it's not supposed to be this instead?

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.sockets.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: No, check the link i posted to the tutorial from the official socket.io website.

Comment: Your code is almost identical to code that's in Sams Teach Yourself Node.js by George Ornbo, 24 Proven One-Hour Lessons.  Hour 13, Example 02, for example.  The code's nearly identical.  I worked through the entire chapter and it worked perfectly.  The code I've shown is really the only significant difference which I can see.  It's p.218 in the book if you wanted to do a little more research.